# Howto configure Apache WSGI for multiple separate Django instances?

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I have an apache instance where I have the following

```
WSGIPythonPath /production/somelocation/django12/lib/python2.4/site-packages/
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1:443>
        WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/project.wsgi
        .....
```

My Django 1.5 app apache config looks like,

```
WSGIPythonPath /production/somelocation/django15/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.2:443>
        ....
        WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/project2.wsgi
```

My /opt/project.wsgi looks like

```
import os
import sys

# django1.2 virtualenv
import site
site.addsitedir("/production/somelocation/django12/lib/python2.4/site-packages")
.....
```

However when I go to the site I still get my default django (1.5) instance. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The other answers mention setting the python path, however using WSGIPythonPath or WSGIPythonHome are not correct. The WSGIPythonPath / WSGIPythonHome can only be set **server-wide**, so no different paths per virtualhost.

You would want to use the [**WSGIDaemonProcess**](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess) **python-path** and **home** arguments to set the python path and your apps home directory per virtualhost.

Also, within your code there is no need to adjust python paths; just make sure your virtualhost config is correct.

Comment: I was talking about python-path, as you just said.
See my second answer, since I couldn't access my httpd-vhost file until now.

Comment: Thanks, Ive used the WSGIDaemonProcess and this works however, Im not setting a user or group and then using "WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}".So Im not sure if this is a security concern ?

Comment: You should not do this when hosting multiple sites on the same machine. You can use **user** and **group** arguments to set the user/group as which the WSGI should be executed.

Comment: Could you please decide who gave you the proper answer? Thanks.

Comment: Ok thanks, so you would you use user1/group1 for site A and user2/group2 for site B ? Thanks for all your help....

Comment: Yes, isolated users/groups per virtualhost

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set `WSGIPythonHome` since you have different Django installations.

`WSGIPythonPath` is used to define additional directories, but this option do not set *default* python installation. So probably, your default python directory also includes *django (1.5)* and recognize this version as the default django version. I do not know your python and django installation and configuration but this might be the reason.

Additional info for [WSGIPythonHome](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonHome)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do with Pyramid:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername hackintosh
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName modwebsocket.local
    ErrorLog "/PythonProjects/MOD_WEBSOCKET/logs/error_log"
    CustomLog "/PythonProjects/MOD_WEBSOCKET/logs/access_log" common

    WSGIDaemonProcess pyramid-modwebsocket user=apero group=staff threads=4 python-path=/PythonProjects/MOD_WEBSOCKET/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup pyramid-modwebsocket

    WSGIScriptAlias /  /PythonProjects/MOD_WEBSOCKET/wsgi/pyramid.wsgi

    <Directory "/PythonProjects/MOD_WEBSOCKET/wsgi">
        WSGIProcessGroup pyramid-modwebsocket
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ai.local
    ErrorLog "/PythonProjects/AI/logs/error_log"
    CustomLog "/PythonProjects/AI/logs/access_log" common

    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIDaemonProcess pyramid-ai user=apero group=staff threads=4 python-path=/PythonProjects/AI/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup pyramid-wizard

    WSGIScriptAlias /  /PythonProjects/AI/wsgi/pyramid.wsgi

    <Directory "/PythonProjects/AI/wsgi">
        WSGIProcessGroup pyramid-ai
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: So, did this and my initial abswer, solve your issue? If yes thanks for giving points.

Answer (score 1):

This topic and the typical causes are detailed in:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html

There is not enough information in your question to properly evaluate which of the problems you are encountering.